# Deducing network parameters from prefix/subnet, using Jinja2 templating language

Tags: math, jinja2, salt-stack

I am working on an opensource project to provide a full stack for small enterprise network or cluster of nodes using Salt and Jinja2.

However, to make the stack compatible with subnets not like /24, /16, and /8, I need to deduce some parameters from prefix/subnet.

Here is an example:

User provides subnet 10.0.0.0 and prefix /23.
I want to deduce that:

netmask is 255.255.254.0 and broadcast is 10.0.1.255

I want also the user to be able to specify other parameters with the same kind of operations to be done after using Salt.

But I fail today to find a way to do that with Jinja2 templating language, to be able to render directly values in Salt Pillar.

You can see in the template designer http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/ that available math operations are limited. I was also considering filters, but couldn't find one.

Does one of you knows a way to realize such IP related operations using basic Math operations ? (so no binaries ones)

With my best regards

Ox

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the built in Jinja filters are rather limited on this.
I think you will need to make a call to a salt module.

If you have Salt 2016.3 or greater, you can call the `netaddress` execution module in your Jinja templates. Make sure the Python module `netaddr` is installed on the targeted minions. Then you can make Jinja calls like this in your Salt states.

```
/tmp/demonstration.txt:
  file.managed:
    - contents:
      - "broadcast: {{ salt.netaddress.cidr_broadcast('10.0.0.0/23') }}"
      - "netmask: {{ salt.netaddress.cidr_netmask('10.0.0.0/23') }}"
```

(Replace the string literal `10.0.0.0/23` with something you have defined in your pillar.)

If you have an earlier Salt version place a file `netaddress.py` in a directory called `_modules` within your `file_roots` (probably `/srv/salt/state/_modules`):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import netaddr  

def cidr_broadcast(str_net):
    net = netaddr.IPNetwork(str_net)
    return net.broadcast

def cidr_netmask(str_net):
    net = netaddr.IPNetwork(str_net)
    return net.netmask
```

Execute `sudo salt <target_minion> saltutil.sync_all` and it should work as well.

However I'm not sure what you mean by "*to be able to render directly values in Salt Pillar*".

If you want to do the same thing within the pillar, you can write pillar SLS files like this:

```
{%- set example_net = '10.0.0.0/23' %}

demonstration:
  example_net:
    net: {{ example_net }}
    broadcast: {{ salt.netaddress.cidr_broadcast(example_net) }}
    netmask: {{ salt.netaddress.cidr_netmask(example_net) }}
```

Note that if you need to write a custom module for pillar rendering, this works a little different, as the pillar is rendered on the master. You will need to set `extension_modules` in your master config and place your module in a directory called `modules` in that case.

Regards,
Dirk

Comment: Very late (like lol, sorry...). At the moment it solved my issue, and I forgot to thank you. So thanks ! :-)